# Android Studio code error

Tags: android-studio

the app was bulding fine, until I added some new layouts and when I run it this error shows within the line of codes

```
enter code 
here public static final class id {
        public static final int Nexus 5 (5_0")=0x7f070001;
        public static final int dummy_button=0x7f070003;
        public static final int fullscreen_content=0x7f070000;
        public static final int fullscreen_content_controls=0x7f070002;
        public static final int switch2=0x7f070004;
```

in second line: public static final int Nexus 5 (5_0")=0x7f070001;
it underlines it red from Nexus 5 (5_0")=0x7f070001; till the end of that line. what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `Nexus 5 (5_0")` is not a valid identifier for a Java variables. You cannot have spaces, for example, in the names. When you declared the new layouts with the new ids, Android Studio automatically took the ID names and created the Java equivalents. The rest of your variables have a valid name and follow the naming convention for resource ids.

Try renaming the ID (in the layout file) to something similar to `nexus_5.`